# how to implement custom breakpoints on bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement custom breakpoints to collapse navbar at 1050. My navbar is working perfectly on mobile view and desktop view but on tablet view menu bar is appearing in two rows. I have implemented the below mentioned code but it is also not working. please help!

```
enter code here
@media (max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-header {
    float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media (max-width: 1050px) { /*Custom breakpoint*/
 .navbar-header {
 float: none;
}
 .navbar-toggle {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:-10px;
}
 .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
 display: block!important;
}
 .collapsing {
 overflow: hidden!important;
}
 .navbar-collapse.collapse {
 display: none!important;
}
 .navbar-collapse {
margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
 .navbar-nav {
 float: none!important;
 margin: 0;
}
 .navbar-nav>li {
 float: none;
}
 .navbar-nav>li>a {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
 position: static;
 float: none;
 width: auto;
 margin-top: 0;
 border: 0;
}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much sir for your help but it is also not working ..:(